# Add a limit to the html table

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table

I'm pulling data using php dom parser and writing it to the table but I don't want all of this data to come in I want to add a limit How can I do it

```
 <?php $st = 0;foreach ($c as $item): ?>                       
    <tr>
      <td> <?php echo $saat = $item->find("time",0)-> plaintext;  ?> </td>
      <td> <?php echo $takim1 = $item->find("span.homespan",0)-> plaintext;  ?> </td>
      <td><?php echo $takim2 = $item->find("span.awayspan",0)-> plaintext;  ?> </td>
      <td> <?php echo $oran = $item->find(".tipdiv > span",0)-> plaintext;  ?> </td>
    </tr>
 <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: How is the limit defined? By the count of table rows, or by some other method? If the former, perhaps add a count variable and stop displaying when you reach the number of table rows that you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to limit the number of items you're displaying, you can simply set a counter, and stop the loop when the count reaches that limit. For example:

```
<?php
$limit = 10;

for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++)
{
  $item = $c[$i];
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $saat = $item->find("time",0)-> plaintext; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $takim1 = $item->find("span.homespan",0)-> plaintext; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $takim2 = $item->find("span.awayspan",0)-> plaintext; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $oran = $item->find(".tipdiv > span",0)-> plaintext; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

change your foreach with for loop

```
$limit = 20;
for($i=0; $i < $limit ; $i++ ) {
//do some loop until limit reached
}
```